# "Посамостоятельней". ПО — предлог или приставка?

Tags: орфография, морфология, приставка

Только что написала свой "собеседнице" в форуме Математика: "Будьте по самостоятельней". И задумалась: а какую роль играет здесь "по"? Это предлог? Или приставка и надо писать вместе? Текстовый редактор подчеркивает последний вариант красным.
А если это предлог, что он означает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, уверен, что это не предлог именно потому, что у него нет никакой функции.
Погуглил и нашел вот такое вот значение приставки *-по*: *с наречиями и прилагательными указывает на сравнительную степень. побольше, поменьше ([пруф](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE-)).* То есть посамостоятельней пишется вместе, хотя я бы не использовал в этом слове приставку, потому что и без неё слово звучит прелестно и понятно.

Comment: Может и так. Подожду, кто еще что скажет. А смысл у этого "по" есть - смягчение высказывания, чтобы оно не выглядело командой! Такой вот "дамский" вариант...

Answer (score 1):

Текстовый редактор подчеркивает слова, которых нет в словаре. Слово "посамостоятельней" явно производное. Это одна из причин, объясняющих отсутствие слова в тезаурусе. В вашем случае по-, конечно, не предлог, а приставка, значение которой приводит Валентин. Она, кроме всего прочего, придает производному слову (наречию) оттенок смягчения признака (качества). Сравните: тише - потише, больше - побольше, мягче - помягче. И мне кажется, что смысл команды передает все же глагол, а не наречие.

Comment: Ну, значит, я правильно почувствовала. Просить "будьте самостоятельней" я не решилась, мало было надежды ;-))